# Remove dict_values from a list/set

Tags: python

Code:

```
candidates_new_fp_votes = {'a': 24, 'b': 0, 'c': 17, 'd': 23, 'e': 0}
print(candidates_new_fp_votes)
tst_list = candidates_new_fp_votes.values()
print(tst_list)
```

print(tst_list) outputs dict_values([24, 0, 17, 23, 0])

How can I make tst_list into [24, 0, 17, 23, 0]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `list(candidates_new_fp_votes.values())`...

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn I have tried the following:                                              tst_list = list(all_candidates_fp_votes.values()) and i'm getting the error:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Then you assigned something else to the name `list`. Don't do that.